# Transform constexpr expressions into template non-type parameter

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, constexpr, non-type

In the following example I want to transform some `constexpr` values into template non-type parameters. 
Here I have some `constexpr` values `a1` and `a2`. I can use there (also `constexpr`) data-member `d` as non-type template parameters for the template `B`.

But if I try to take place this sort of transformation in some function `transform` this clearly doen't work anymore, since the parameter `tuple` isn't considered `constexpr`.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <tuple>

template<auto N>
struct A {
    inline static constexpr auto size = N;
    const uint8_t d[N] {};
};
template<auto N, auto... II>
struct B {};

constexpr auto a1 = A<2>{1, 2};
constexpr auto a2 = A<3>{2, 3, 4};
constexpr auto t1 = std::tuple(a1, a2);

constexpr auto b1 = B<a1.size, a1.d[0], a1.d[1]>{};
constexpr auto b2 = B<a2.size, a2.d[0], a2.d[1], a2.d[2]>{};

template<typename T>
constexpr auto transform(const T& tuple) {
    constexpr auto x1 = std::get<0>(tuple); // NOK
    constexpr auto b1 = B<x1.size, x1.d[0], x1.d[1]>{}; // NOK 
    return std::tuple(b1);
}

constexpr auto t2 = transform(t1);

int main() {
}
```

The question is then: how can I make this sort of transformation. My idea is to write a meta-function with tuple `t1` as parameter. But I can't get it right ...

Comment: It is impossible. `constexpr` can only go one way through the call stack

Comment: Agreed. So I tried to write a template meta-function: using compile-time iteration over the tuple, etc. But I get stuck ...

Comment: Argument of function are not `constexpr`, using `std::integral_constant` is a way to pass constant via argument (but `A<N>` is not a valid candidate).

Comment: I am not at all clear what "this sort of transformation" is supposed to mean. BTW, VC++17 gives up at the line "constexpr auto a1 = A<2>{1,2};" Does not know what to do with the initializer values.

Comment: So, VC17 isn't capable of doing a aggregate initializsation

Comment: Jarod42: do I get you right that you mean the array-members should be `std::integral_constants`? Then I have to use a` std::tuple` instead of the array ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++17 you can pass a `constexpr` lambda returning your argument:

```
constexpr auto t2 = transform([&] { return t1; });
```

Inside the function you can "call" the lambda and assign to a `constexpr`:

```
template<class Tuple_>
constexpr auto transform(Tuple_ tuple_) {
  constexpr auto tuple = tuple_();
  // ...
```

Some research (thanks @wimalopaan) shows that this idiom has been described

- in an [audience comment to a talk at C++Now 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMB9oXFobJc&t=94m28s) by an anonymous commenter (referring to "some discussion on slack")
- in a [blog post](https://mpark.github.io/programming/2017/05/26/constexpr-function-parameters/#c17) by Michael Park

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/073103acf18f80b6

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

// not sure how robust this macro is...
#define CONSTEXPR_ARG(arg) [&] { return arg; }

template<auto N>
struct A {
    inline static constexpr auto size = N;
    const uint8_t d[N] {};
};
template<auto N, auto... II>
struct B {};

constexpr auto a1 = A<2>{1, 2};
constexpr auto a2 = A<3>{2, 3, 4};
constexpr auto t1 = std::tuple(a1, a2);

constexpr auto b1 = B<a1.size, a1.d[0], a1.d[1]>{};
constexpr auto b2 = B<a2.size, a2.d[0], a2.d[1], a2.d[2]>{};

template<class Tuple_>
constexpr auto transform(Tuple_ tuple_) {
  constexpr auto tuple = tuple_();
  constexpr auto x1 = std::get<0>(tuple); // NOK
  constexpr auto b1 = B<x1.size, x1.d[0], x1.d[1]>{}; // NOK
  return std::tuple(b1);
}

constexpr auto t2 = transform(CONSTEXPR_ARG(t1));

template<class T>
void inspect(const T& t) {
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  inspect(t2);
}
```

Output:

```
void inspect(const T&) [with T = std::tuple<B<2, 1, 2> >]
```

Comment: This might be a pattern: instead of defining `constexpr` variables, define them in a surrounding lambda and use the lambda as function argument.

Comment: is there a name for this idiom?

Comment: @wimalopaan: I do not know a name for this idiom. The first time I played with it was after watching a video recording of (IIRC) "`constexpr` ALL the things!" by Ben Deane and Jason Turner where this idiom was mentioned in a comment from the audience. Now I can not find the comment any more.

Comment: Just found it: it is in the https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMB9oXFobJc Version of the talk at the very end at time 1:34:45. That is awesome ....

Comment: I don't know if Jason Turner invented the term IIEF (immediately invoked function expressions), but I think, this little idiom here deserves also a helpful name.